# GDAL Changing Values

Tags: raster, gdal

For context I am working with a .tif file that I have warped and changed all nodata values to -9999.

Is there any way with GDAL to take all values from this .tif file that are greater than -9999 and convert them to another value?

I have tired to do this with ogr2ogr but I don't know enough SQL to make that work.

Comment: are you sure you're working with a shape file (=vector format)? Your problem description fits more to the raster format..

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right, I've been staring at this code for too long. I'm working with a .tif file that has been rastered.

Comment: I've updated the question with the correct format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nodata value can be changed with [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) utility:

```
gdalwarp -srcnodata "-9999" -dstnodata "0" original_raster.tif new_raster.tif
```

To change raster data (values greater then -9999 to 100) use [calculator](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html):

```
 gdal_calc.py -A original_raster.tif --outfile=new_raster.tif --calc="100*(A>-9999)+A*(A<=-9999)"
```

Comment: As far as I understood, OP wants to change the data itself. Not setting the nodata value.

Comment: @RoVo that is correct

Comment: Use calculator then (for example to convert values greater then -9999 to 100): gdal_calc.py -A original_raster.tif --outfile=new_raster.tif --calc="100*(A>-9999)+A*(A<=-9999)"