# How to change nodata with gdal_translate

Tags: gdal-translate

I am trying to create a tiff file using gdal_translate.

Initially my `noDataValue` was 0.0, but my client suggested that `- noDataValue` should be -9999.0, so I changed it to -9999.0.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff  -a_nodata -9999.0 -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_ullr -26.62 45.099999999999994 75.46 -6.82 -co INTERLEAVE=BAND -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -ot Float32 shape_19790101.tif shape_19790101_optimized.tif
```

But now I am getting following suggestion

> You set the noDataValue to -9999, but you did not recompute the imagine and change the value of the "noDataPixels"

Can anybody explain what exactly this means ?

Comment: You are looking for [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262399/138363).  gdal_translate -a_nodata only sets the nodata value to -9999 instead of 0, but won't change the value of the no data pixels (those with 0 in the source raster)